# Configuring WCF Transport security for IIS6 over SSL

Tags: wcf, security, ssl, iis-6, transport

I've been attempting to set up WCF transport security using SSL on IIS6.

The client is on a seperate machine on the same domain.

I understand the premise of certificates, root CA etc and have a working set of certs for message security and can use these no probs in the same enviroment set up. (i've learn't a lot over the last week :)

I'm having an nightmare trying to get my client to authenticate against the IIS 6 service when i switch it to SSL. Always recieving 'annonymous authetication not allowed' when calling.

IN IIS i have

- a root signed CA cert set on the site for SSL port 443 
  (if i browse the https:// svc page i can see the IE padlock and the page says you need a cert to communicate)

under secure communications i have

- require SSL channel
- require 128 bit encryption
- require client certificates
- enable client certificate mapping  (set up with a many to 1 mapping to a admin account on the IIS box for now matched on the cert subject O field )

under web site security (authentication and access control)

- Anonymous access = ON
- Intergrated Windows Authentication = OFF
- basic Authentication = ON

For the client wsHttpBinding i have a certificate ready to authenticate and a custom endpoint behaviour to supply this info but i don't think its getting this far!

**UPDATED SERVER CONFIG**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="CertificateWithTransport">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="credentialConfig">                
            <endpoint address="https://svnvmig02/Service1.svc" 
                        binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                        bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport" 
                        contract="WCFServiceCertificate.IService1">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="credentialConfig">                   
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>                    
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**UPDATED CLIENT CONFIG**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://svnvmig02/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="svnvmig02" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"/>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**EDIT:** 
Probably worth mentioning that my VS projects are 3.5 but IIS6 is running .net4

With the amended config (thanks Fabio ;) i can now IE browse the address https://svnvmig01/Service1.svc from the client machine and see the generated svc page which allows me to click on the wsdl URl which is also available.

The majority of the pages i have found on the net refer to selfhosting or IIS7....I'm hoping IIS7 support is better ;)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like IIS is configured correctly. Could you post your service and client config please.

Comment: Hi Fabio, think i may have taken a step back here...IIS config remains unchanged but where i've tinkered i'm getting.... 
Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service

Comment: Does this article help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074.aspx. Can you reduce your config to something similar to the one described in the article?

Comment: OK Fabio, I've updated the configs to reflect the link you sent. I failed to mention i'm on framework 3.5 but i see from the .net 4 version of the help MSDN page you can add <protocolMapping> which is not available in 3.5. May be this is the issue as my service is 3.5 but IIS6 is set to version 4?

Comment: You shouldn't need the <serviceCredentials> section in the service behavior, can you try to drop that. Also, the subject names don't seem to match? The client config has 'svnmig02' and the server config has 'clientCert'. Please can you review your certificates setup in details: where they are located on each machine, subject names, whether they are self-signed etc

Comment: <serviceCredentials> ahh yes..sorry about that Fabio, i'v been a bit cut / copy / paste happy caused by MSDN document frustration! I've revised the config as suggested but with no luck. I've checked the cert 'svnvmig02' all seems ok its signed by seperate CA 'WEB01' (a third box solely acting as the root CA), the chain also authenticates ok when viewed and both the CA cert and the local 'svnvmig02' certs are in appropriate stores.... My / Trusted Root Certification Authorities / Trusted People

Answer (score 1):

Your config includes:

```
https://svnvmig02:8091/Service1.svc
```

The normal port for ssl is 443.

It may be that the request is not going to the site that you expect it to go to. Therefore, you are getting and unexpected error message.

Check the IIS logs to make sure which site is receiving the request.

Comment: Hi Shiraz, I've tried amending this to the same URL as the one i surf in IE to see the cert padlock etc

ie. https://svnvmig02/Service1.svc 

No change, but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue here may be that you have IIS set to:

> Anonymous access = OFF

I use transport security on several of my servers, and all the IIS6 ones have that setting ON, not OFF. This also corresponds to the error message you provided:

> 'annonymous authetication not allowed'

Without anon access off, IIS will either want the user to enter a username/password, or pass along a windows / active directory / kerberos credentials.

Comment: cheers rally25rs, thats got rid of the 'service requires anonymous authentication enabled' at the very least now i'm back to 'page requires client certificate'